# Gnuplot, how to draw a 3d mesh from different textual input files

Tags: 3d, gnuplot, mesh

I have a few text files with 3 columns and would like to create a 3d plot with a mesh.
The files look like:

***file1.txt***

```
X    Y    Z  

1  1 1

2 1 4

3 1 6

4 1 9
```

***file2.txt***

```
X    Y    Z  

1  2 3

2 2 4

3 2 10

4 2 12
```

***file3.txt***

```
X    Y    Z  

1  3 12

2 3 11

3 3 13

4 3 12
```

As you can notice all the y values from each file are constant because I'm looking to study variation of Z as a function Y.
Now of course I'm aware that I can produce the 3d plots using

```
splot "file1.txt" u 1:2:3 w l  \
     ,"file2.txt" u 1:2:3 w l  \
     ,"file3.txt" u 1:2:3 w l
```

However, I would like to create a grid with lines of constant X so that I have a mesh that shows the contours (It becomes clearer this way how Z changes with X and Y). Any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: Yes, you can probably again do something with a command line utility, like in your other question. Buth without knowing if the other solution worked it is quite pointless to go on answering...

Comment: well, yes my previous problem is resolved, thank you for that!

Comment: If you solved your problem you can post the answer for the other users. Please verify if the data presents the _doubled spaces_ as you write in the question, it can lead to different answers. (`1  3 12` and the line after `2 3 11`, two whitespaces  vs only one).